# Android: How to create Array of ArrayAdapters for Array of Spinners

Tags: android, arrays, spinner, android-arrayadapter

Android 4.0+
I have 10 spinners, have loaded into an array
I am trying to associate with 10 ArrayAdapters, using an array of ArrayAdapters.
Not working...

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>[] adpPPI;

for (int ppiCntr = 0; ppiCntr < 10; ppiCntr++) {

//NOTE 1: next statement gets resource id, works ok
    int res_array = getResources().getIdentifier(
        "com.my:array/ppi" + Integer.toString(ppiCntr + 1) + "_array", null, null);

// NOTE 2: creating the array adapter provides null pointer error. 
// because I need to initialize it somehow? how? 
    adpPPI[ppiCntr] = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
        getApplicationContext(), res_array, R.layout.psm_simple_spinner_item);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you never initialise `adpPPI`.

Inbetween the array declaration ...

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>[] adpPPI;
```

... and trying to assign values to its indices ...

```
adpPPI[ppiCntr] = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(...);
```

... you never create the array.

In short, you'll probably want to add something like this somewhere inbetween the two:

```
adpPPI = new ArrayAdapter[10];
```

Hint: make sure to do that somewhere above the `for` loop.

Note: You can't create arrays of a generic type in Java, so you'll have to use the raw type (or perhaps better said: make the initialisation of the array type-less). Alternatively, you could use a Collection/List in stead of an array.

Comment: I tried:   adpPPI = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>[10];
before the for loop, but I get the error in Eclipse:
"Cannot create a generic array of ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>"

Comment: You might want to swap out `ppiCntr` with an actual number in case the variable doesn't have a sensible value before the `for` loop. Updated the answer to illustrate that.

Comment: Ah yes, silly me. Java doesn't do array of a generic type. In stead, you're going to have to use the 'raw' type. Eclipse will warn you about that, but if you know what you're doing, you should be fine. I'll update the answer again. Alternatively, use a Collection/List in stead of an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>> adpPPI = new Vector<ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>>();

for (int ppiCntr = 0; ppiCntr < 10; ppiCntr++) {

//NOTE 1: next statement gets resource id, works ok
    int res_array = getResources().getIdentifier(
        "com.my:array/ppi" + Integer.toString(ppiCntr + 1) + "_array", null, null);

// NOTE 2: creating the array adapter provides null pointer error. 
// because I need to initialize it somehow? how? 
    adpPPI.add(ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
        getApplicationContext(), res_array, R.layout.psm_simple_spinner_item));
}
```

Try the above code, You missed initializing your array.

Comment: get the error in eclipse: Eclipse: "Cannot create a generic array of ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>"

Comment: Thanks so much! I decided to stick with the 'raw' type arrayadapter for now. But I understand what you have suggested and am happy to see this elegant approach too.